# Derivation of Integer Partition from Partition of a Set

Tags: integer-partitions, set-partition

**Definition.**
Let $A$ be a non-empty set. A collection $P$ of subsets $A_1,A_2,A_3,\ldots$ of $A$ is called a **partition** of $A$ if the following three conditions hold:

1. $\emptyset \notin P$,
2. $A_1 \cup A_2 \cup A_3 \cup \cdots = A$, and
3. For all $i$ and $j$, if $i \ne j$, then $A_i \cap A_j = \emptyset$.

**Definition.** Let $n$ be a positive integer. A partition of $n$ is a finite sequence $\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\lambda_3,\ldots\lambda_k$ of positive integers such that $\lambda_1 \ge \lambda_2 \ge \lambda_3 \ge \cdots \ge \lambda_k$ and
$$\lambda_1+\lambda_2+\lambda_3+\cdots+\lambda_k = n.$$

I want to know a derivation of the word "partition" in the integer from the partition of a set.
Here's my attempt.

First, define a relation $R$ on the set $\Bbb N$ as follows:
For all $a,b \in \Bbb N,$
$$aRb \iff (\exists I \subseteq \Bbb N) (a,b) \in I.$$

Let $n \in \Bbb N$.
I have already shown that $R$ is an equivalence relation on $\Bbb N$.
Hence, $\Bbb N$ could be partitioned into equivalence classes. Call them
$$[\lambda_k, \lambda_{k-1}), \ldots, [\lambda_2, \lambda_1), [\lambda_1, +\infty),$$
where $\lambda_1 \ge \lambda_2 \ge \cdots \ge \lambda_k$ and
$\lambda_1+\lambda_2+\cdots+\lambda_k=n$. Let
$$P=\{[\lambda_k, \lambda_{k-1}), \ldots, [\lambda_2, \lambda_1), [\lambda_1, +\infty)\}.$$

But, I got stucked here. Any ideas? Thanks in advanced.

Comment: 1) Why would you like this? 2) Your definition of $R$ makes no sense, whatever you mean by $(a,b)$ (either open interval or ordered pair).

Comment: Because I want to know the use of the word "partition" in the integer from the partition of the set.

Comment: @AnneBauval Sorry, I mean it is an ordered pair.

Comment: @AnneBauval I'm sorry. What do you mean about 'why'?

Comment: Anyway, it makes no sense. $(\exists I\subseteq N)(a,b)\in I$ is equivalent to $(a,b)\in\Bbb N,$ which never holds.

Comment: I just wanna to learn the link/relation from each

Comment: Really? But, if no, why in the integer partition using word 'partition', which is the same as the word 'partition' in the partition of a set?

Comment: Why never holds? I want to say that $a$ related to $b$ iff there exists an interval/subset of $\Bbb N$ such that $a$ and $b$ are in the same interval.

Comment: Then, don't write $(a,b)\in I$ but $\{a,b\}\subseteq I.$ But then it *always* hold! (and there are many possible $I$'s)

Comment: Got it. But, how to link them? :(

Answer (score 1):

I can only see the following vague link: any partition of a positive integer $n$ may be obtained by partitioning a set $E$ of $n$ elements, and taking the number of elements of each subset of $E$ belonging to the partition.